# AutoMapping Object with Constructor Arguments

Tags: c#, automapper

I am trying to configure AutoMapper to work with a class which requires a constructor argument. I've done quite a bit of online research into this, and found several examples...but they either don't use instance-based AutoMapper, or they are for older versions of AutoMapper.

I'm using AutoMapper to deep clone objects. Here's the profile I've created:

```
public class ScannerAutoMapProfile : Profile
{
    public ScannerAutoMapProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<AzureConfiguration>();
        CreateMap<CommunityUser>();
        CreateMap<Community>();
        CreateMap<Contact>();
        CreateMap<DatabaseConnection>();
        CreateMap<DatabaseConfiguration>();
        CreateMap<LoginManagement>();
        CreateMap<MaxLoadSeconds>();
        CreateMap<ScanTime>();
        CreateMap<ScanningAcceleration>();
        CreateMap<ScanningWindow>();
        CreateMap<ScanningInterval>();
        CreateMap<Scanning>();
        CreateMap<SearchParameterUser>();
        CreateMap<SearchParameter>();
        CreateMap<ScannerConfiguration>();
    }

    private void CreateMap<TModel>()
    {
        CreateMap<TModel, TModel>();
    }
}
```

The problem is occurring with ScannerConfiguration, which takes a single string parameter.

Here's the Autofac module I'm using:

```
public class AutoMapperModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load( ContainerBuilder builder )
    {
        base.Load( builder );

        var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes( assemblies )
            .Where( t => typeof(Profile).IsAssignableFrom( t ) && !t.IsAbstract && t.IsPublic )
            .As<Profile>();

        builder.Register( c => new MapperConfiguration( cfg =>
            {
                foreach( var profile in c.Resolve<IEnumerable<Profile>>() )
                {
                    cfg.AddProfile( profile );
                }
            } ) )
            .AsSelf()
            .SingleInstance();

        builder.Register( c => c.Resolve<MapperConfiguration>().CreateMapper( c.Resolve ) )
            .As<IMapper>()
            .SingleInstance();
    }
}
```

(thanx to http://www.protomatter.co.uk/blog/development/2017/02/modular-automapper-registrations-with-autofac/ for this).

I can successfully instantiate an IMapper, which shows the Autofac stuff is working properly. But when I attempt to call Map:

```
_onDisk = Mapper.Map<ScannerConfiguration>( _inMemory );
```

it fails with a "ScannerConfiguration has no parameterless constructor" exception.

Unfortunately, while I'm pretty sure I need to provide some options to that Map() call, I haven't been able to figure out how to do it. The parameter I need to pass in to the constructor is a public property of ScannerConfiguration, called SourceFilePath.

Comment: The most relevant details are the source class and the destination class. I don't think the code you've posted is actually part of the problem. If not it might be beneficial to remove it so that the question is more helpful for future people who search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `ScannerConfiguration` requires a parameter, why don't you initialize it yourself?

```
var sc = new ScannerConfiguration("some string value");
_onDisk = Mapper.Map( _inMemory, sc );
```

Comment: Thanx @Alexei. I didn’t realize AutoMapper could map onto an existing object. I thought it always had to create a new instance.

Comment: @MarkOlbert - oh, no. This would be a great limitation. There are various scenarios when this is need even if there are no constructors with parameters. E.g. You want to update a data model (Entity Framework) using data provided by a service (service model). You get the data model from the database, map the data from the service model and then save.

Answer (score 1):

If Automapper can't create an instance of the destination using a default constructor, you can give Automapper a function that calls a constructor and returns the new instance with `ConstructUsing`. After it constructs the object it continues mapping as usual.

For example here's a source and destination class. The destination class can't be created without calling a non-default constructor:

```
public class SourceClass
{
    public string SourceStringProperty { get; set; }
    public int OtherSourceProperty { get; set; }
    public bool SameNameInBoth { get; set; }
}

public class DestinationClass
{
    public DestinationClass(string destinationString)
    {
        DestinationStringPropertyFromConstructor = destinationString;
    }

    public string DestinationStringPropertyFromConstructor { get; }
    public int OtherDestinationProperty { get; set; }
    public bool SameNameInBoth { get; set; }
}
```

The mapping would look like this:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<SourceClass, DestinationClass>()

        .ConstructUsing(hasString => new DestinationClass(hasString.SourceStringProperty))

        .ForMember(dest => dest.OtherDestinationProperty,
            opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.OtherSourceProperty));
});
```

I added the other properties just to demonstrate that other than specifying a constructor, the other configuration details are all the same.

Comment: Thanx, @ScottHannen. Sorry to be dense, but do you know what it would look like using the AutoMapper instance approach (i.e., not using the static Mapper)? I keep having a lot of problems understanding examples I see using the static approach when I have to use the instance approach.

Comment: In that scenario, if you open up one of those mapper profile classes, this same mapping would go in one of those. Not dense - for the first few years I used Automapper I didn't even know there was more than one way to configure it.